# Determining Google Map

Tags: google-maps

I have an issue with respect to Google map. There is Google map API already implemented. Is there anyway to find out if it is free Google map API or Google map API for business usage.

Answer (score 2):

the google map api is not totally free there is a max limit to use this
check this page [Compare Google Maps API for Business with Google Maps API standard edition](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps-compare.html)

Comment: is that free limit been applied in Google map API V2 or in Google map API V3?

Comment: @kaustubhshukla ya there is limit on both

Comment: so, for business usage, they have same API like free one or something else?

Comment: @kaustubhshukla please check the link in answer

Comment: but i am not able to figure out which edition is consumed ....